# Will low grades for a minor on my trascript affect my chances of getting into grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, psychology

So, I started out as an Information Technology major and now decided to pursue Psychology. I wanted to also pursue a minor in Computer Science instead because I am 1 class away from a minor. I am undecided what exactly I want to do after I graduate, but I do know I want to go to some sort of graduate school. So far, most of my grades have been at least a "C", most of them being A's. This semester I am taking 3 computer science classes and a calculus class. I have been struggling this semester and I don't count on having high grades (I realized I am not as interested in this field and have trouble understanding the subject matter). I think a few of my grades will end up being D's, but my GPA should still be over a 3.0. Once I start my psychology classes, I think I can bring my GPA back up.

So, I was wondering if graduate schools would worry about the low grades I may receive this semester even though they are not included in my psychology major. I also do not plan on retaking any classes.

Comment: Welcome. Just want to give you a heads up that questions like this may be voted to close due to being mostly opinion based. There are just basically too many variables for us to foretell your chance. Generally no magic there, A > B > C > D >>>> F. Subjects that are closer to the grad school program's have higher weight. Try your best not to get a series of Ds this round, and end your final semester in a high note.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think it is possible at this point... that's why I am asking.

Comment: @mty, fields and institutes matter, but GPA > 3 should at least prevent automatically being screened out. There are other ways to compensate a relatively weak GPA. Work, internship, research experience, other exams like GRE etc. Keep this goal, and the sooner you figure out what field you'd go into, the better as you can start getting relevant resume items to strengthen your portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have been doing rather poorly in your current major but will change to another where you expect to do better. Assuming that you do, in fact, do *very* well in psychology and all of your later grades are better than your earlier ones, you may be ok. You can explain that you were ill suited to your first choice of study and changed, and now you are doing fine.

That would be a winning position for some, but not all, institutions, but you have what you have in your background. Make the most of your future, of course, and work harder, if necessary, to be a success.

Short story: Not a great position, but not necessarily a losing one. Make the future count as you can't change the past.